# why "+" button is not working to add the input value in the quantity given in the table?

Tags: php, html

following code : for query and the button. Upon clicking the button "+" it only refresh the page . The inputted value should be added in the quantity left .

[image]

```
        <input type="number" size="2" title="Input value" placeholder="0" 
        id="doni" name="Value"  required 
        maxlength="4" />
        <input type="submit" value="+" name="button" title="Add" onclick 
        =action = "addQuan.php">


        <?php
       // configuration (addQuan.php)
      include('connect.php');

      // new data
      $id = $_POST['memi'];
      $a = $_POST['code'];
      $b = $_POST['bname'];
      $c = $_POST['Value'];
      $d = $_POST['price'];
      $e = $_POST['supplier'];

      $f = $_POST['qty_left'];
      $i = $_POST['dname'];
      $t = $f + $c;

     // query
     $sql = "UPDATE products 
     SET qty_left=? 
     WHERE product_id=?";
     $q = $db->prepare($sql);
     $q->execute(array($t,$id)); 
     header("location: products.php");

     ?>
```

Comment: where's this function `limitText`

Comment: onclick=action="addQuan.php" ???

Comment: what's the error? You mean to say by pressing + Sign it is not adding text fields?

Comment: yes @BitsPlease

Comment: please see the picture

Comment: @Johan THANK YOU SIR :)

Comment: Try solving using @Johan answer. If it's still issue then pls tell will help u

Comment: yes it works :)

Comment: @BitsPlease thank you too :)